# What is GHCi's default implementation of MonadError?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, ghci

Consider the following test function:

```
testError :: (Error e, MonadError e m) => Bool -> m ()
testError True  = return ()
testError False = throwError $ strMsg "hello world"
```

At the GHCi prompt, I can do the following:

```
*Main> testError False :: Either String ()
Left "hello world"
*Main> testError True :: Either String ()
Right ()
```

Because I have stated Either String _ as the expression's type, it uses the Either String implementation of MonadError. I was assuming that if I didn't specify an implementation of MonadError myself, or call this function from another function, allowing for type inference, I would get an error. Instead:

```
*Main> testError True
*Main> testError False
*** Exception: user error (hello world)
```

It would appear that GHCi is providing some kind of "default" error monad. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expressions typed at the prompt in GHCi are typechecked twice: first wrapped in `print`, and if that fails for any reason, then as an IO operation.  In your case the first attempt would fail due to ambiguity, but the second attempt typechecks using the `IO` instance of `MonadError`.